# best practices for adding my own tools and configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, conventions

So, I am currently writing some scripts to gather and bulk report break-in attempts on my server. The scripts itself are working, but I am wondering where I should put my config files and the script itself.

I thought about making an installer that would copy the required binaries in `/usr/local/bin` but for the configuration file I am not sure.

I have had this problem in the past when I was installing for example `automysqlbackup`, some program that will automate running and tidying up mysql backups. Do I create a new directory in `/etc` with a name of my choosing or is `/var/lib` the place for additions that do not come from packages? What is the conventional place to store these configuration files? Should I keep the shell scripts and binaries and configuration files together in one place thats completely different?

Comment: One customary place for config files of scripts/executables in `/usr/local/bin` is `/usr/local/etc`.

Comment: I didnt even realize there is more than ``bin`` to ``/usr/local/``..

Answer (score 0):

You could take the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) as a guide.

The summary of this (focusing on the two paths you mention) is:

- if it is a text file edited by the administrator put it in `/etc`
- if it is application state (database, cache, ...) put it in `/var/lib`

Comment: I actually had a look at [/opt : Add-on application software packages](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) and now I am not sure if I should use ``/opt`` and put everything in a directory there or spread the files out through ``/usr/local/`` using an installer script